# Stop all .R files from loading as italic

Tags: r

at some point in the last few weeks, I must have changed a default formatting setting by accident, but I can't figure out what, or how to undo it.

All the text in my .R files is now italic by default. I can change the font back under Format -> Font and save it, but the next time I open the file it loads as italic again.

Have I overlooked something under 'options', below? Any other thoughts?

Using R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray", Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)

```
> options()
$add.smooth
[1] TRUE

$bitmapType
[1] "quartz"

$browser
[1] "/usr/bin/open"

$browserNLdisabled
[1] FALSE

$CBoundsCheck
[1] FALSE

$check.bounds
[1] FALSE

$citation.bibtex.max
[1] 1

$continue
[1] "+ "

$contrasts
        unordered           ordered 
"contr.treatment"      "contr.poly" 

$defaultPackages
[1] "datasets"  "utils"     "grDevices" "graphics"  "stats"     "methods"  

$demo.ask
[1] "default"

$deparse.cutoff
[1] 60

$device
function (title, width, height, pointsize, family, antialias, 
    type, file = NULL, bg, canvas, dpi) 
{
    if (missing(type) || type %in% c("", "native", "Cocoa")) {
        check <- Sys.getenv("_R_CHECK_SCREEN_DEVICE_", "")
        msg <- "screen devices should not be used in examples etc"
        if (identical(check, "stop")) 
            stop(msg, domain = NA)
        else if (identical(check, "warn")) 
            warning(msg, immediate. = TRUE, noBreaks. = TRUE, 
                domain = NA)
    }
    new <- list()
    if (!missing(title)) 
        new$title <- title
    if (!missing(width)) 
        new$width <- width
    if (!missing(height)) 
        new$height <- height
    if (!missing(pointsize)) 
        new$pointsize <- pointsize
    if (!missing(family)) 
        new$family <- family
    if (!missing(antialias)) 
        new$antialias <- antialias
    if (!missing(bg)) 
        new$bg <- bg
    if (!missing(canvas)) 
        new$canvas <- canvas
    if (!missing(type)) 
        new$type <- type
    if (!missing(dpi)) 
        new$dpi <- dpi
    if (!checkIntFormat(new$title)) 
        stop("invalid 'title'")
    if (!is.null(file) && !checkIntFormat(file)) 
        stop("invalid 'file'")
    d <- check.options(new, name.opt = ".quartz.Options", envir = .Quartzenv)
    .External(C_Quartz, d$type, file, d$width, d$height, d$pointsize, 
        d$family, d$antialias, d$title, d$bg, d$canvas, if (is.na(d$dpi)) NULL else d$dpi)
    invisible()
}
<bytecode: 0x7fd5f74441a8>
<environment: namespace:grDevices>

$device.ask.default
[1] FALSE

$digits
[1] 7

$dvipscmd
[1] "dvips"

$echo
[1] TRUE

$editor
[1] "vi"

$encoding
[1] "native.enc"

$example.ask
[1] "default"

$expressions
[1] 5000

$help_type
[1] "html"

$help.search.types
[1] "vignette" "demo"     "help"    

$help.try.all.packages
[1] FALSE

$HTTPUserAgent
[1] "R (3.5.1 x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 x86_64 darwin15.6.0)"

$install.packages.compile.from.source
[1] "interactive"

$internet.info
[1] 2

$keep.source
[1] TRUE

$keep.source.pkgs
[1] FALSE

$locatorBell
[1] TRUE

$mailer
[1] "mailto"

$matprod
[1] "default"

$max.print
[1] 99999

$menu.graphics
[1] TRUE

$na.action
[1] "na.omit"

$nwarnings
[1] 50

$OutDec
[1] "."

$pager
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/pager"

$papersize
[1] "a4"

$PCRE_limit_recursion
[1] NA

$PCRE_study
[1] 10

$PCRE_use_JIT
[1] TRUE

$pdfviewer
[1] "/usr/bin/open"

$pkgType
[1] "both"

$printcmd
[1] "lpr"

$prompt
[1] "> "

$repos
                               CRAN 
"https://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran" 

$rl_word_breaks
[1] " \t\n\"\\'`><=%;,|&{()}"

$scipen
[1] 0

$show.coef.Pvalues
[1] TRUE

$show.error.messages
[1] TRUE

$show.signif.stars
[1] TRUE

$str
$str$strict.width
[1] "no"

$str$digits.d
[1] 3

$str$vec.len
[1] 4


$str.dendrogram.last
[1] "`"

$stringsAsFactors
[1] TRUE

$texi2dvi
[1] "/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi"

$timeout
[1] 60

$ts.eps
[1] 1e-05

$ts.S.compat
[1] FALSE

$unzip
[1] "/usr/bin/unzip"

$useFancyQuotes
[1] TRUE

$verbose
[1] FALSE

$warn
[1] 0

$warning.length
[1] 1000

$width
[1] 128
```

Comment: What text editor are you using? I can't see how this can be an R issue but rather a setting in you editor: Rstudio, emacs, vim, atom...

Comment: I'm not using a text editor or Rstudio, I'm opening any .R file in the R.app GUI 1.70 (7543 El Capitan build), R version 3.5.1, and the text is italicized. I can create an R file on a different machine, in a different environment, or using vim, but when I open it it's italicized.